# I am getting segmentation error /fault when I run the below code

Tags: c, memory, graph, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

I am new to C. I get a segmentation error when I run the below graph traversal algorithm program in an online C compiler. I know the error is due to accessing the memory that has not been initialized or not accessible but I don't know where the error occurs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define max 5
struct vertex{
    char name;
    bool isVisited;
};
int queue[max];
int rear = -1, front = 0, queueCount = 0, vertexCount = 0;
struct vertex* adjList[max];
int adjMat[max][max];
void insert(int data){
    queue[++rear] = data;
    queueCount++;
}
int delete(){
    queueCount--;
    return queue[front++];
}
bool isEmpty(){
    return queueCount == 0;
}
void addVertex(char name){
    struct vertex* v = (struct vertex*)malloc(sizeof(struct vertex));
    v->name = name;
    v->isVisited = false;
    adjList[vertexCount++] = v;
}
void addEdge(int start, int end){
    adjMat[end][start] = 1;
    adjMat[start][end] = 1;
}
void display(int vertexIndex){
    printf("%c", adjList[vertexIndex]->name);
}
int getAdjUnvisitedVertices(int vertexIndex){
    for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++){
        if (adjMat[vertexIndex][i] == 1 && adjList[i]->isVisited == false){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
void BFS(){
    adjList[0]->isVisited = true;
    display(0);
    insert(0);
    int unvisitedVertex;
    while (!isEmpty()){
        int tempVertex = delete();
        while (unvisitedVertex = getAdjUnvisitedVertices(tempVertex) != -1){
            adjList[unvisitedVertex]->isVisited = true;
            display(unvisitedVertex);
            insert(unvisitedVertex);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++){
        adjList[i]->isVisited = false;
    }
}
void main(){
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < max; j++){
            adjMat[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    addVertex('S');
    addVertex('A');
    addVertex('B');
    addVertex('C');
    addVertex('D');
    addEdge(0,1);
    addEdge(0,2);
    addEdge(0,3);
    addEdge(1,4);
    addEdge(2,4);
    addEdge(3,4);
    printf("Breadth First Traversal : ");
    BFS();
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to find where the error occurs.

Comment: @ kiner_shah I don't know how to use debugger since I am new to C

Comment: Which IDE? Which OS?

Comment: I tried many compilers like OnlineGDB, tutorialspoint IDE, OneCompiler, and programiz.
All shows segmentation error or SIGSEGV error and monitored command dumped core error

Comment: On Online GDB there is an option to Debug your code. But yeah I think you may face difficulty to learn how to use it (it's GDB).

Comment: I used GBD Debugger and i get something like ```34      void display(int vertexIndex){
(gdb) step
35          printf("%c", adjList[vertexIndex]->name);
(gdb) step
putchar (c=65) at putchar.c:25
25      putchar.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) step
27      in putchar.c```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An infinite loop occurs here causing the array boundary exception. Reason is the assignment statement was not executed.

```
 while (unvisitedVertex = getAdjUnvisitedVertices(tempVertex) != -1)
```

To ensure assignment operation take place along with the conditional operator, it needs to be parenthesised.

```
while ((unvisitedVertex = getAdjUnvisitedVertices(tempVertex)) != -1)
```

With this change result is
Breadth First Traversal :
SABCD

Answer (score 2):

Using  `gcc -g -fsanitize=address a.c && ./a.out` results in:

```
=================================================================
==2590725==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: global-buffer-overflow on address 0x563fc7b38394 at pc 0x563fc7b35262 bp 0x7ffe7e7fd600 sp 0x7ffe7e7fd5f8
WRITE of size 4 at 0x563fc7b38394 thread T0
    #0 0x563fc7b35261 in insert /tmp/a.c:14
    #1 0x563fc7b35839 in BFS /tmp/a.c:55
    #2 0x563fc7b35a89 in main /tmp/a.c:80
    #3 0x7fe91f032e49 in __libc_start_main ../csu/libc-start.c:314
    #4 0x563fc7b35139 in _start (/tmp/a.out+0x1139)

0x563fc7b38394 is located 0 bytes to the right of global variable 'queue' defined in 'a.c:9:5' (0x563fc7b38380) of size 20
0x563fc7b38394 is located 44 bytes to the left of global variable 'front' defined in 'a.c:10:16' (0x563fc7b383c0) of size 4
```

Line 14 is:

```
     queue[++rear] = data;
```

So at the problem point, `rear` index exceeds `5`.

Comment: do you mean that error is due to the queue and front variable that I am accessing wrongly??
I don't know anything about g++ so be simple

Comment: @20CSE028AfsalBaaqirA, you should check whether queue is already full before inserting and whether queue is already empty before deleting.

Comment: @Employed Russian Umm when I check isEmpty() and isFull() at delete() and insert() respectively I get an infinite printing of characters (say A).